# How to dynamically display Last Refreshed <time> ago message on webpage that updates based on the elapsed time since the last API call

Tags: javascript, html, express, npm-package

I am new to web development, and I am trying to display "Last Refreshed  ago" on the webpage. Something like this [website](https://trendshashtags.com/twitter-trends/united-states/). I am making API call every 5 minutes, what I would like to achieve is I would like to display text for time 0sec-59 sec as "Last Refreshed 1 sec ago" and so forth. Next for minutes it should display text as "Last refreshed 1 minute ago" , and so on until 5 minutes.As soon API call is made again, then it should display "Last refreshed 0 sec" and continues until 5 minutes ago. Below code has 2 issues

1. As soon as Browser is refreshed it starts the time again from 0 sec, in my case I would like to display continuous time.In provided website link, even if refresh button is pressed on browser you will notice that it display "**Trends last updated 1 min ago**"
2. After end of 5 minutes in below code, time continues for  6 minutes, 7 minutes etc. Even though data for Fetch API is refreshed.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trending Hashtags</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
    <div id="hashtags-container">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be dynamically added here -->
    </div>
    <div id="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">Last Refreshed: -</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        let startTime = 0;

        function startTimer() {
            fetch('/start-time') // Fetch initial start time from server
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    startTime = data.startTime;
                    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000); // Update every second
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching start time:', error));
        }

        function updateTimer() {
            const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Get current Unix timestamp in seconds
            const elapsedSeconds = currentTime - startTime;

            updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds);
        }

        function updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds) {
            const timestampElement = document.querySelector('#timestamp-container .timestamp');
            if (timestampElement) {
                const timeAgo = formatTime(elapsedSeconds);
                timestampElement.textContent = `Last Refreshed: ${timeAgo} ago`;
            }
        }

        function formatTime(seconds) {
            const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            const secs = seconds % 60;
            return mins > 0 ? `${mins} min` : `${secs} sec`;
        }

        function fetchAndUpdateHashtags(containerId) {
            fetch('/trends')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching trends:', error));
        }

        function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
            const hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
            hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                const trendItem = document.createElement('div');
                trendItem.className = 'trend-item';
                trendItem.innerHTML = `
                    <span>${index + 1}.</span>
                    <span><span>${item.hashtag}</span></span>
                    <span class="text-secondary">${formatTweetVolume(item.tweetCount)}</span>
                `;
                hashtagsContainer.appendChild(trendItem);
            });
        }

        function formatTweetVolume(volume) {
            if (volume >= 1000) {
                return (volume / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
            }
            return volume;
        }

        fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container'); // Initial fetch
        startTimer(); // Start the timer

        setInterval(() => {
            fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container');
        }, 300 * 1000); // Fetch every 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    </script>

    <style>
        .trending-card {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Twit = require('twit');

const app = express();

const apikey = '';
const apisecretkey = '';
const accesstoken = '';
const accesstokensecret = '';

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/start-time', (req, res) => {
  const startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  res.json({ startTime });
});

app.get('/trends', (req, res) => {
  const timeAgo = req.query.time || '5min'; // Default to 5 minutes
  const params = { id: '23424977' };

  fetchTrendingHashtags(params)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({ data, timeAgo });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

function fetchTrendingHashtags(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    T.get('trends/place', params)
      .then((result) => {
        const trends = result.data[0].trends;

        const validTrends = trends.filter((trend) => trend.tweet_volume !== null);

        const sortedTrends = validTrends.sort((a, b) => b.tweet_volume - a.tweet_volume);

        const topTrends = sortedTrends.slice(0, 10);

        const simplifiedTrends = topTrends.map((trend) => {
          return {
            hashtag: trend.name,
            tweetCount: trend.tweet_volume,
          };
        });

        resolve(simplifiedTrends);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching trends:', error);
        reject('Error fetching trends');
      });
  });
}

const timeIntervals = [
  { minutes: 5, containerId: 'hashtags-container' }, // Fetch every 5 minutes
  // Add other time intervals here if needed
];

timeIntervals.forEach((interval) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const newParams = { id: '23424977' };
    fetchTrendingHashtags(newParams)
      .then((data) => {
        updateHashtagsContainer(interval.containerId, data.data);
        console.log(`Fetched trends for ${interval.minutes} ago`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error fetching trends for ${interval.minutes} ago:`, error);
      });
  }, interval.minutes * 60 * 1000);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**Code after SO User recommendation:**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trending Hashtags</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
    <div id="hashtags-container">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be dynamically added here -->
    </div>
    <div id="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">Last Refreshed: -</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        let startTime = localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(updateTimer, 1000); // Update every second
        }

        function updateTimer() {
            const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Get current Unix timestamp in seconds
            const elapsedSeconds = currentTime - startTime;

            updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds);
        }

        function updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds) {
            const timestampElement = document.querySelector('#timestamp-container .timestamp');
            if (timestampElement) {
                const timeAgo = formatTime(elapsedSeconds);
                timestampElement.textContent = `Last Refreshed: ${timeAgo} ago`;
            }
        }

        function formatTime(seconds) {
            if (seconds >= 300) {
                startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
                return '0 sec';
            }

            const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            const secs = seconds % 60;
            return mins > 0 ? `${mins} min` : `${secs} sec`;
        }

        function fetchAndUpdateHashtags(containerId) {
            fetch('/trends')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching trends:', error));
        }

        function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
            const hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
            hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                const trendItem = document.createElement('div');
                trendItem.className = 'trend-item';
                trendItem.innerHTML = `
                    <span>${index + 1}.</span>
                    <span><span>${item.hashtag}</span></span>
                    <span class="text-secondary">${formatTweetVolume(item.tweetCount)}</span>
                `;
                hashtagsContainer.appendChild(trendItem);
            });
        }

        function formatTweetVolume(volume) {
            if (volume >= 1000) {
                return (volume / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
            }
            return volume;
        }
    
   startTimer(); // Start the timer

// Remove this line: fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container');

setInterval(() => {
    fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container');
}, 300 * 1000); // Fetch every 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    </script>

    <style>
        .trending-card {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Twit = require('twit');

const app = express();

const apikey = '';
const apisecretkey = '';
const accesstoken = '';
const accesstokensecret = '';

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});


app.get('/start-time', (req, res) => {
  const startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  res.json({ startTime });
});

app.get('/trends', (req, res) => {
  const timeAgo = req.query.time || '5min'; // Default to 5 minutes
  const params = { id: '23424977' };

  fetchTrendingHashtags(params)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({ data, timeAgo });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});


function fetchTrendingHashtags(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    T.get('trends/place', params)
      .then((result) => {
        const trends = result.data[0].trends;

        const validTrends = trends.filter((trend) => trend.tweet_volume !== null);

        const sortedTrends = validTrends.sort((a, b) => b.tweet_volume - a.tweet_volume);

        const topTrends = sortedTrends.slice(0, 10);

        const simplifiedTrends = topTrends.map((trend) => {
          return {
            hashtag: trend.name,
            tweetCount: trend.tweet_volume,
          };
        });

        resolve(simplifiedTrends);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching trends:', error);
        reject('Error fetching trends');
      });
  });
}

const timeIntervals = [
  { minutes: 5, containerId: 'hashtags-container' }, // Fetch every 5 minutes
  // Add other time intervals here if needed
];

// Function to update hashtags container
function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
  // ... (your code for updating hashtags container)
  const hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
            hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                const trendItem = document.createElement('div');
                trendItem.className = 'trend-item';
                trendItem.innerHTML = `
                    <span>${index + 1}.</span>
                    <span><span>${item.hashtag}</span></span>
                    <span class="text-secondary">${formatTweetVolume(item.tweetCount)}</span>
                `;
                hashtagsContainer.appendChild(trendItem);
            });
}

// Set intervals for data fetching
timeIntervals.forEach((interval) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const newParams = { id: '23424977' };
    fetchTrendingHashtags(newParams)
      .then((data) => {
        updateHashtagsContainer(interval.containerId, data.data);
        console.log(`Fetched trends for ${interval.minutes} ago`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error fetching trends for ${interval.minutes} ago:`, error);
      });
  }, (interval.minutes * 60 - 5) * 1000); // Adjust interval to 295 seconds
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **localStorage** to store the start time so that it persists even after page refresh.

Calculate the elapsed time based on the **stored start time** and the **current time**.

Update the **timestamp** based on the elapsed time and ensure that it doesn't exceed **5 minutes**.

Update the time in real-time even when the **page is refreshed**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trending Hashtags</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Trending Hashtags</h1>
    <div id="hashtags-container">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be dynamically added here -->
    </div>
    <div id="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">Last Refreshed: -</span>
    </div>

    <script>
        let startTime = localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(updateTimer, 1000); // Update every second
        }

        function updateTimer() {
            const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Get current Unix timestamp in seconds
            const elapsedSeconds = currentTime - startTime;

            updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds);
        }

        function updateTimestamp(elapsedSeconds) {
            const timestampElement = document.querySelector('#timestamp-container .timestamp');
            if (timestampElement) {
                const timeAgo = formatTime(elapsedSeconds);
                timestampElement.textContent = `Last Refreshed: ${timeAgo} ago`;
            }
        }

        function formatTime(seconds) {
            if (seconds >= 300) {
                startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
                return '0 sec';
            }

            const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            const secs = seconds % 60;
            return mins > 0 ? `${mins} min` : `${secs} sec`;
        }

        function fetchAndUpdateHashtags(containerId) {
            fetch('/trends')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching trends:', error));
        }

        function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
            const hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
            hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                const trendItem = document.createElement('div');
                trendItem.className = 'trend-item';
                trendItem.innerHTML = `
                    <span>${index + 1}.</span>
                    <span><span>${item.hashtag}</span></span>
                    <span class="text-secondary">${formatTweetVolume(item.tweetCount)}</span>
                `;
                hashtagsContainer.appendChild(trendItem);
            });
        }

        function formatTweetVolume(volume) {
            if (volume >= 1000) {
                return (volume / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
            }
            return volume;
        }
    
   startTimer(); // Start the timer

// Remove this line: fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container');

setInterval(() => {
    fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container');
}, 300 * 1000); // Fetch every 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    </script>

    <style>
        .trending-card {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Your server.js File:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Twit = require('twit');

const app = express();

const apikey = '';
const apisecretkey = '';
const accesstoken = '';
const accesstokensecret = '';

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/start-time', (req, res) => {
  const startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  res.json({ startTime });
});

app.get('/trends', (req, res) => {
  const timeAgo = req.query.time || '5min'; // Default to 5 minutes
  const params = { id: '23424977' };

  fetchTrendingHashtags(params)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({ data, timeAgo });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

function fetchTrendingHashtags(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    T.get('trends/place', params)
      .then((result) => {
        const trends = result.data[0].trends;

        const validTrends = trends.filter((trend) => trend.tweet_volume !== null);

        const sortedTrends = validTrends.sort((a, b) => b.tweet_volume - a.tweet_volume);

        const topTrends = sortedTrends.slice(0, 10);

        const simplifiedTrends = topTrends.map((trend) => {
          return {
            hashtag: trend.name,
            tweetCount: trend.tweet_volume,
          };
        });

        resolve(simplifiedTrends);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching trends:', error);
        reject('Error fetching trends');
      });
  });
}

const timeIntervals = [
  { minutes: 5, containerId: 'hashtags-container' }, // Fetch every 5 minutes
  // Add other time intervals here if needed
];

// Function to update hashtags container
function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
  // ... (your code for updating hashtags container)
}

// Set intervals for data fetching
timeIntervals.forEach((interval) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const newParams = { id: '23424977' };
    fetchTrendingHashtags(newParams)
      .then((data) => {
        updateHashtagsContainer(interval.containerId, data.data);
        console.log(`Fetched trends for ${interval.minutes} ago`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error fetching trends for ${interval.minutes} ago:`, error);
      });
  }, (interval.minutes * 60 - 5) * 1000); // Adjust interval to 295 seconds
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: ..Thank you one issue solved. However, now there is issue with API call/data fetched from API call (out of sync with the time). The Fetched API data is getting refreshed between 4-5mins instead of 5 mins also if refresh button of browser is clicked then it is refreshing the fetched data.I would like to refresh the data every 5 minutes only.  I added the updated code based on your suggestion in question. One thing I noticed is when I run node server.js file in VS Code, I am receiving "Error fetching trends for 5 ago: ReferenceError: updateHashtagsContainer is not defined".

Comment: Data Refresh Timing: You've set the interval to be every 5 minutes, but it seems that the actual fetching is happening a little bit before the 5-minute mark due to the processing time. To make sure the data is refreshed as close to 5 minutes , you can subtract a small offset from the interval time.

Page Refresh Issue: The data is being refreshed on page refresh because the fetchAndUpdateHashtags function is called both on initial load and inside the interval function. To prevent data refresh on page reload, you should remove the fetchAndUpdateHashtags call from outside the interval.

Comment: Thank you, but now facing 2 issues.I have updated the code per you suggestion and added to question as well. 1) Timer resets again to 0 as soon as refresh button is pressed in the browser. 2) Fetched hashtags are not getting displayed on the page if I try http://localhost:3001/trends, then I can the data. But If try http://localhost:3001, cannot see the data.